# Flutter: Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, api

What I am trying is to get the data from an API to the mobile Flutter application. The API should be set up fine. The only thing where I am struggling with is this error code. I know it has something to do with a `List` but I didn't find the solution.

The error flutter gives:

[image: Flutter error]

Api:
[image: sql api]

JokeModel.dart:

```
JokeModel jokeModelFromJson(String str) => JokeModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String jokeModelToJson(JokeModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());


class JokeModel{
final int klantId;
final String mailaddres;
final String wachtwoord;
final String klantvoornaam;
final String tussenvoegsel;
final String klantachternaam;
final String bedrijfsnaam;
final String telefoonnummer;

JokeModel({
  required this.klantId,
  required this.mailaddres,
  required this.wachtwoord,
  required this.klantvoornaam,
  required this.tussenvoegsel,
  required this.klantachternaam,
  required this.bedrijfsnaam,
  required this.telefoonnummer,
});

factory JokeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return JokeModel(
  klantId: json["klantId"],
  mailaddres: json["mailaddres"],
  wachtwoord: json["wachtwoord"],
  klantvoornaam: json["klantvoornaam"],
  tussenvoegsel: json["tussenvoegsel"],
  klantachternaam: json["klantachternaam"],
  bedrijfsnaam: json["bedrijfsnaam"],
  telefoonnummer: json["telefoonnummer"],
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  "KlantId": klantId,
  "Mailaddres": mailaddres,
  "Wachtwoord": wachtwoord,
  "Klantvoornaam": klantvoornaam,
  "Tussenvoegsel": tussenvoegsel,
  "Klantachternaam": klantachternaam,
  "Bedrijfsnaam": bedrijfsnaam,
  "Telefoonnummer": telefoonnummer,
  };
}
```

Repository.dart:

```
class JokeRepository {
  final String _baseUrl = "https://---.---.-.--:port/api";

  Future <JokeModel> getJoke() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_baseUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jokeModelFromJson(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load joke");
    }
  }
}
```

Joke_bloc.dart:

```
class JokeBloc extends Bloc<JokeEvent, JokeState> {
  final JokeRepository _jokeRepository;

  JokeBloc(this._jokeRepository) : super(JokeLoadingState()) {
    on<LoadJokeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(JokeLoadingState());
      try {
        final joke = await _jokeRepository.getJoke();
        emit(JokeLoadedState(joke));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(JokeErrorState(e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is returning an array, not a JSON object and `JokeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` expects a `Map`, not a `List`.

I'd recommend returning from the API a proper JSON object like below. This way it's even possible to return an error status and error message.

```
{
  success: true,
  result: [
    {
      klantId: 1,
      mailaddress: "XXXXXX"
      ...
    },
    {
      klantId: 2,
      mailaddress: "XXXXXX"
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You'd need also to create, for example, a `JokesResponse` serializable class like so:

```dart
JokesResponse jokesResponseFromJson(String str) =>
    JokesResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String jokesResponseToJson(JokesResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class JokesResponse {
  final bool success;
  final List<JokeModel> result;

  JokesResponse({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  JokesResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : success = json["success"],
        result = (json["result"] as List)
            .map((joke) => jokeModelFromJson(joke))
            .toList();

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "result": result.map((joke) => jokeModelToJson(joke)),
      };
}
```

Comment: So if i understand you correctly. The API is not returning an JSON object. which means i have to change the API. So it will show the result from the database the same way u mention in the answer. And i have to adjust the Model a little.

Comment: Exactly... but you don't have to change the `JokeModel`. Just create a new one `JokesResponse` for the API response to get the list of `JokeModel`s